# Adding values to member fields of object in List<T> at same index

Tags: c#

I have a collection of type object called MHP.  MHP has multiple member fields(Name, AC, Par_ID, etc).
I create a List;

```
private List<MHP> mhpList = new List<MHP>();
public List<MHP> MHPList
{ get { return mhpList; } set { mhpList = value; } }
```

And I populate a portion of the fields with values in a for loop by creating a new object:

```
mhpList.Add(new MHP
{
 MHP_Name = something,
 MHP_AC = a number
});
```

Now I want to populate the remaining field with a value and I’m doing so by creating a new object, but this obviously places the value in a new index of the collection;

mhpList[0] MHP_Name = ‘Something’, MHP_AC = ‘#’, MHP_ParId = null.

mhpList[1] MHP_Name = null, MHP_AC = null, MHP_ParID = ‘something’

I’ve tried creating a new list and adding a new object to that list then using the following to add the new list to mhpList:

mhpList.AddRange(newList)

as wellas  and mhp.InsertRange, but each time this add a new index of the object in the collection.  How do I add values to unpopulated fields within the SAME index of a collection?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. You have mhpList with MHP objects which have Name and AC. You want to set Par_ID? Or what? On what conditions you want to set that id?

Comment: Your 3rd code block doesn't look like C# at all?

Comment: Do you know the index?  Or have some other way to uniquely identify the element in the list?  Clearly functions like `Add` and `AddRange` are going to, well, add new elements to the list.  But you can retrieve an element from the list and modify it.  In what way does that not work?

Comment: Much of this code doesn't compile. Show us exactly what you're doing and where the results differ from what you expect. As it stands, it's difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I applogize, but the last two sections aren't code, I indented them in order to make it more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just access the item using it's index:

```
mhpList = new List<MHP>();

mhpList.Add(new MHP
{
 MHP_Name = something,
 MHP_AC = a number
});

mhpList[0].MHP_ParId= "Something";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mhpList[0].MHP_ParID = something;
```

In more detail, you should use methods of your MHP object, not method of the List. All the list knows is there are some MHP objects in it. What a list can do is:

- Add a MHP to the list
- Remove a MHP from the list
- Fetch a MHP from the list

If you want to change the fields inside a specific MHP, that's not something concerned with the list, but with MHP objects. You fetch the object, and then modify it. Then, if it's a reference object (class) you're done. If it's a value object (struct), you must re-add it to the list, like:

```
MHP obj = mhpList[0];
obj.MHP_ParID = something;
mhpList[0] = obj;
```